# Electron only allow save to a folder

Tags: electron

I need for my user to only be able to select a folder to be saved. Is it possible in electron to only allow folders to be selected via `dialog#showSaveDialog`? Filters only work on file extensions, there's no mention of filtering folders only.

Comment: If you need to save to a folder, it's better to not use the system dialog. A better option would be to show the user an input to set the file name and then save the file on a specific folder, since that is the part you don't want your users to select.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the [showOpenDialog](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/dialog.md) with the `openDirectory` flag for this.

Logically it doesn't make sense to "save" a folder since it is just a 
virtual "container". Allowing the user to select a folder to "open" in order to "save" data into it is the usual flow.

Comment: Looks good, especially combined with `promptToCreate`. Thanks